# Android app shell "no such file or directory", fine in a file explorer and adb

Tags: java, android, ioexception, nosuchfileexception

I'm trying to copy a file from `/path/to the/file.ext` (yes, it has spaces, I suspect this is at least part of the trouble) to `/data/data/com.my_pkg.app/file.ext`.

In my (root) app, I do:

```
String cmd = "su -c \"cp /path/to\\ the/file.ext /data/data/com.my_pkg.app/file.ext\"";
try {
    Process process;
    process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this raises an `IOException: no such file or directory`.

Checking my sanity, I opened a root file explorer app, navigated to the path above, copied it, and pasted it in my app's directory, and everything was fine.

Why is `cp` not finding it? - the file explorer app must be doing the same (well, with modification that makes it work!) thing underneath all that GUI.

***Edit:** the full error:*

```
W/System.err( 2441): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). 
     Command: [su -c "cp /path/to\ the/file.ext /data/data/com.my_pkg.app/file.ext"] 
     Working Directory: null 
     Environment: [ANDROID_ROOT=/system, 
          EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE=/mnt/shell/emulated, 
          LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, 
          EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET=/storage/emulated, 
          ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib,             
          EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/emulated/legacy, 
          ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=10, 
          ANDROID_DATA=/data, 
          PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, 
          ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, 
          BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/webviewchromium.jar, 
          ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,0, 
          ANDROID_STORAGE=/storage]
```

Comment: Note that your **java** IOException **does not** come from `cp` not finding a file.  Rather it is likely coming from failing to find the executable - which would actually be `su` rather than `cp`.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Failing to find what executable?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Never mind, you edited in. How do I "help it find" `su` then?

Comment: You could give the explicit path - assuming you *have* an su for it to find.  You might want to try a series of simpler tests building up to your actual goal to figure out where the problem(s) are - though I agree the embedded quotes may be *one of* them.

Comment: Ah so I just give the path to it, as though it's not in `PATH`, and just any old program being passed some arguments? i.e. replace `su` with `path/to/su`?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually though, when I used the same code for different `cmd` (still `su`), it worked fine, requested root permissions, so clearly had no trouble finding `su`.

Comment: Replace `/path/to..` with original path of file.

Comment: @Yuvi I'm not completely stupid, this is my code, I just simplified the path of original file to `/path/to..` to make it clearer/more readable for you guys.

Comment: @OllieFord Are you able to execute your command from adb shell ?

Comment: One interesting question would be if any shell ends up processing your argument list (with its escaped space) or not - that would depend a bit on how your specific implementation of `su` works.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Does it working over adb point back to a `su` issue? I'm afraid I don't really understand your last comment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I get the same error by providing path to `su` - but it isn't requesting root permissions. Strange. That's probably why it doesn't work, but I mean it's strange it isn't requesting.

Comment: You may be able to try using `su` from the adb shell (even though it is unnecessary there).  Or you could try it from within a terminal app like connectbot, where you actually would need to escalate from an unprivileged app userid.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was using `su` when Yuvi asked if my command worked from adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer, because it resolved my question *as I asked it*, and so should solve this problem for any one happening across this by search. For me, however, [it just led to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079633/android-shell-copy-file-fails-silently-with-no-errors).

By changing the string:

```
String cmd = "su -c \"cp /path/to\\ the/file.ext /data/data/com.my_pkg.app/file.ext\"";
```

to an array (that the rest of the code as-is concatenates/builds):

```
String[] cmd = {"su", "-c", "\"cp /path/to\\ the/file.ext /data/data/com.my_pkg.app/file.ext\""};
```

All the errors were resolved. I can't tell you why, but at least they are.